# How do I repair Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) after accidentally running `history | script`?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a Windows Subsystem Linux installation (the distro is Ubuntu). I use it to build a Rails project and deploy branches to the server. Things worked OK for the last year.

Today I accidentally run this code:

```
history | script
```

After that it says something like "started script...typescript"

I did not know how to get out of that, so I just closed and restarted the Ubuntu terminal (inside Windows)

Now when I start the Ubuntu terminal it says Installing, this may take a few minutes... and that has gone on for 15 minutes now.

Can somebody help me? Did I accidentally mess up the distro by running that script? What does it do exactly?

And how can I get the distro back to before?

Thanks!

Comment: Script is not for scripting (read manual).

Comment: depending on what commands you had in your history, the damage may be irreparable, and you'll have to install from scratch. It's true that `history` will usually prepend a number to each line, resulting in a lot of harmless 'command not found' filling up a `typescript` file, but depending on the syntax, some commands may be run, with catastrophic consequences. (eg. for any line like `3333 true || rm -fr *` the `rm -fr *` will be run, even if in  the original command it wasn't ;-)

Comment: Just remove and reinstall WSL and see whether that helps.

Answer (score 2):

`history` lists your recent commands, or all past commands, or all but some filtered ones such as `cd` (depending on setup). It is then passing them to script to execute and to log. However every history line will start with a number, so that will produce a lot of `command not found` error messages.

If you are lucky then you just filled up the disk with a file called `typescript`. If you are unlucky then it re-ran your history, but in the wrong context, and broke things.

Remove the file `typescript`, and re-test. Then consider re-installing.

But before re-install, what user were you running as? If root then it may be very broken, else it will be just user files. (Dose WSL have a concept of root?)

Comment: yes indeed it was root and things were very broken :((( i had to reinstall WSL. Btw is there a way to block certain command from running? history | script is EXTREMELY DANGEROUS and looks very similar to history | grep script (which is what I wanted to type...)

Comment: If WSL has the concept of root, then don't run as root; use `sudo` (if WSL has it); Use different user accounts, to protect files; And use a revision control system (with a remote copy of the repository), for all user files, so that you can get your files back. (this should be a new question, but has probably been asked before)